# User Custom Dashboard

Tags: customization, dashboard

I wondering is there any way/plugin to configure the User Dashboard or Panel. I know there already has a plugin called [WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/) able to do this, but the plugin so far is not support for custom post type. What a shame.

My goal is make the user dashboard look like the frontend as much as possible. The original backend is too 'Wordpress' feel. I don't want my client to feel that way. Can I use the frontend theme integrated into the backend dashboard?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a way to style the backend.  On one level, you could just create a custom admin theme ([Codex description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes)).

On another level, you could use a plugin like [White Label CMS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/white-label-cms/) to completely re-brand WordPress.